# Session Array not working

Tags: php, session

So I'm creating an array in a session but for some reason when I try to add stuff to it, it no longer is an array. I'm not exactly sure what is happening.

ADDING THE ITEM

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['printsID']) && !isset($_SESSION['printsNum'])){
    $_SESSION['printsID']=array();
    array_push($_SESSION['printsID'],$_GET['itm']);
    $_SESSION['printsNum']=array();
    array_push($_SESSION['printsNum'],$_GET['num']);
    header('Location: google.com');
}
else{
    array_push($_SESSION['printsID'],$_GET['itm']);
    array_push($_SESSION['printsNum'],$_GET['num']);
    header('Location: http://www.repmofbla.com/SimmonsRedone/');    
}
```

GETTING THE ITEM

```
if(isset($_SESSION['printsNum'])){  
     $cartItems = array_sum($_SESSION['printsNum']);    
     $cartItems += sizeof($_SESSION['artwork']);
}

else{
     $cartItems = sizeof($_SESSION['artwork']);
}
```

Any help would be great. Thank you guys :)

(I'm also not the best with PHP so I know there is probably a more efficient way to do this. Respect please)

MORE DETAILS: The parts are on different pages. What's weird is when you first upload the get script it works. As soon as you use the Add script it quits working and then the array's no longer "exist", but if I reupload the get script it works again. It's the weirdest thing I've ever encountered.

Comment: `array_push` treats the array as a stack, which is not what you want. Try `$_SESSION['printsNum'] = $_GET['num']` instead to set the key directly to that value. Also, to see what's in your session to confirm it worked, you can use `var_dump($_SESSION)`

Comment: Did you even started your session?

Comment: Don't see any `session_start`?

Comment: You check that BOTH `$_SESSION['printsID']` AND `$_SESSION['printsNum']` are not set. What happens when only one has been set? The other one would not be initialized as an array.

Comment: I have started the session

Comment: @JaceBayless On both pages?

Comment: @Rizier123 Yep, I also added more details to explain the problem a bit more.

Comment: I think we need more information about other session-related parts of your code...

Comment: try this code. see what you get print_r($_SESSION['printsID']);

Answer (score 2):

That's because, you are trying to redirect to different domain. Redirecting to different domain doesn't carry the session forward.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this code in a blank PHP, try it out - might be able to help you figure something out, but it completely works on my side.

```
<form action="currentPage.php" method="get">
    <button name="itm" value="ball">Ball</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="num" value="1234">
</form>

<br />

<form action="currentPage.php" method="get">
    <button name="itm" value="box">Box</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="num" value="4321">
</form>

<br />

<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['printsID']) && !isset($_SESSION['printsNum'])) {
    $_SESSION['printsID']=array();
    array_push($_SESSION['printsID'],$_GET['itm']);
    $_SESSION['printsNum']=array();
    array_push($_SESSION['printsNum'],$_GET['num']);
}

else {
    array_push($_SESSION['printsID'],$_GET['itm']);
    array_push($_SESSION['printsNum'],$_GET['num']);
}

print_r(array_values($_SESSION['printsID']));
print_r(array_values($_SESSION['printsNum']));

?>
```